# Is it possible hiding/not making JSON-LD structured data visible easily to user?

Tags: json-ld, structured-data

Is it possible hiding/not making JSON-LD structured data visible easily to user, but recognizable for bots? The effort I put into making the structured data for my website should not be easily copied by competitors.
Any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you intend to differentiate between a bot and a competitor (which could also run a bot)? If, for example, you only make it visible to selected search engine bots, 1.) all other bots (e.g., from smaller search engines) that could be interested in your structured data won’t be able to see it, and 2.) the search engines might not like it if you serve them different content than your human visitors get to see.

Comment: No, what I mean, is load the Json-LD script dynamically into HTML. It would be recongnizable by Google and not that easy by competitors if they don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [embed JSON-LD inside a script tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#embedding-json-ld-in-html-documents). That hides it from end users but makes it still visible in the source code. You can also dynamically embed such script blocks. You then need some way to differentiate between good/bad bots in the backend.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't completely understand what you mean. I allready embed JSON-LD in a script tag  <script type="application/ld+json">. 
Do you mean I should save the js and just call <script src="/XXX/js/JSON.js"></script> in my <head> section?

Comment: Do you think it woud work this way?
<link rel="alternate" href="/JSON.js" type="application/ld+json" />

Comment: Hmm, sorry I am asking and answering by myself...
Ever heard about the possibility of making a Custom HTML Tag in Google Tag Manager. Seems to be quite easy to implement the whole <script>. I am allready working with GTM on my page.

Comment: Yeah, what you would do would be similar to the GTM. You would write a small script that looks, e.g., for <link rel="alternate" type="application/ld+json" src=".." /> tags and if it finds them, loads the referenced file and then embeds it dynamically as script block. Google doesn't process link tags but supports dynamically embedded script blocks

Comment: Thank you very much! You were extremly helpful!

Comment: @MarkusLanthaler could you please elaborate a bit more on "That hides it from end users but makes it still visible in the source code." I'm not sure I understand. If an end user would view the source code they would see the JSON-LD data?

Comment: Yes, they would see it if they would open the developer tools